# ManyToMany new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "NULL" given

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony4

I have a ManyToMany relation in my Symfony 4.2.6 application and I would like for it to be possible to have this to be null.

So my first entity SpecialOffers is as follows :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SpecialOfferRepository")
 */
class SpecialOffer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Neighbourhood", inversedBy="specialOffers")
     */
     private $neighbourhood;

     public function __construct()
    {
        $this->neighbourhood = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Neighbourhood[]
     */
    public function getNeighbourhood(): Collection
    {
        return $this->neighbourhood;
    }

    public function addNeighbourhood(Neighbourhood $neighbourhood): self
    {
        if (!$this->neighbourhood->contains($neighbourhood)) {
            $this->neighbourhood[] = $neighbourhood;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeNeighbourhood(Neighbourhood $neighbourhood): self
    {
        if ($this->neighbourhood->contains($neighbourhood)) {
            $this->neighbourhood->removeElement($neighbourhood);
       }

       return $this;
   }
}
```

It is related to the neighbourhood class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\NeighbourhoodRepository")
 */
class Neighbourhood implements ResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SpecialOffer", mappedBy="neighbourhood")
     */
    private $specialOffers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->specialOffers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

        /**
     * @return Collection|SpecialOffer[]
     */
    public function getSpecialOffers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->specialOffers;
    }

    public function addSpecialOffer(SpecialOffer $specialOffer): self
    {
        if (!$this->specialOffers->contains($specialOffer)) {
            $this->specialOffers[] = $specialOffer;
            $specialOffer->addNeighbourhood($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSpecialOffer(SpecialOffer $specialOffer): self
    {
         if ($this->specialOffers->contains($specialOffer)) {
            $this->specialOffers->removeElement($specialOffer);
            $specialOffer->removeNeighbourhood($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And finally the form is

```
class SpecialOfferType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'neighbourhood',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Neighbourhood::class,
                    'label' => 'form.neighbourhood.label',
                    'translation_domain' => 'Default',
                    'required' => false,
                    'placeholder' => 'form.neighbourhood.all'
                ]
             );
        }
   }
```

But when I don't select a specific neighbourhood for the Special offer in my form I get the following error :
    `Could not determine access type for property "neighbourhood" in class "App\Entity\SpecialOffer": The property "neighbourhood" in class "App\Entity\SpecialOffer" can be defined with the methods "addNeighbourhood()", "removeNeighbourhood()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "NULL" given.`

Is there anyway I can make it so that my special offer either contains and array of neighbourhoods or just null ?

I feel like I'm overlooking something really obvious, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test =>

```
$builder
            ->add(
                'neighbourhood',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class' => Neighbourhood::class,
                    'label' => 'form.neighbourhood.label',
                    'translation_domain' => 'Default',
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'placeholder' => 'form.neighbourhood.all'
                ]
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your fields on the entities are both many-to-many, thus expecting an array (or similar) and the form field is of `EntityType`, which will return one Entity of the expected type or `null`, I feel like there is some form of asymmetry.

I would consider using the [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) from the start or at least setting the [`multiple`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) option on the form to `true`, so that the return value is an array.

Another option would be to add a `DataTransformer` to the form field, which turns null into an empty array and one entity into an array of one entity, and vice-versa.